# Issues installing Python 3.8.10 on macOS 12.3 Monterey

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, apple-m1, macos-monterey

Anyone having issues installing python 3.8.10 on macOS Monterey M1 Mac? Any version I try to install using `pyenv install` gives me this error:

```
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew python-build: use readline from homebrew Downloading Python-3.8.10.tar.xz... -> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.10/Python-3.8.10.tar.xz Installing Python-3.8.10... python-build: use readline from homebrew python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.3 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/yg/s2w3pfj172v6kdwx7hvmq65m0000gn/T/python-build.20220322155830.88129 Results logged to /var/folders/yg/s2w3pfj172v6kdwx7hvmq65m0000gn/T/python-build.20220322155830.88129.log

Last 10 log lines: checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no checking for clang++... no configure:

By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "clang++". If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.

checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a bug report make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I've tried almost all questions across Google Search without success =(. I've tried to install using `asdf python plugin and pyenv.`

Answer (score 40):

Apple introduced a change that resulted in its breaking.

In your specific case `pyenv install 3.8.13` should work.

For others on different versions should check [this thread](https://issueantenna.com/repo/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2284)

Or use any of these versions 3.7.13, 3.8.13, 3.9.11 and 3.10.3

Comment: "...Or use any of these versions 3.7.13, 3.8.13, 3.9.11 and 3.10.3" >> Great! These patches are very important as they allow to install any of the minor versions that otherwise can't be installed. May be you could add some bold here rahulg.

Comment: **3.7.13, 3.8.13, 3.9.11 and 3.10.3**

^ seconded, this is great info

Comment: for python 3.6 i was able to install version **3.6.15** (`pyenv install 3.6.15`) - _macOS Monterey v12.0.1_

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me.

Install gcc first;

```
brew install gcc
```

And then with gcc run pyenv installation.

```
CC=/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-11 pyenv install 3.8.10
```

[image]

Comment: I got the hint to get past this issue from this response. I installed gcc using homebrew but slightly changed the pyenv command  `CC=gcc pyenv install 3.9.12`

Comment: Turns out my homebrew-installed gcc lives under `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/bin/gcc-11`, so I had to modify the command accordingly.

Answer (score 14):

```
brew install gcc && CC=`which gcc-11` pyenv install 3.8.10
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why but setting the compiler to gcc-11 worked. Seems to have something to do with clang I guess

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't need to install `gcc` with `brew`! It might fall you in trouble much more!

There is a bundled `gcc` in `Apple Command Line Tools` which you can find it through below command:

```
which gcc
```

Be careful to don't add any version specific number to `gcc`! something like `gcc-11` or `gcc-12` and so etc.
Then check the found `gcc` is located under `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/` directory. The desired output would be something like this:

```
$ which gcc
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/gcc
```

If everything is Ok, mean you run simple `which gcc` command and it found `gcc` and the found path is under `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/` directory, you can install your python through `pyenv` using following command:

```
CC=`which gcc` pyenv install 3.8.6
```

you can install any version of python which is available and you need.

If you faced to any issue please comment it, it might help us to make answer more clear and helpful to you.

Comment: my `which gcc` shows `/usr/bin/gcc` path, how to switch to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/gcc` ?

Comment: but `gcc --version` shows `InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

Comment: @Vadim `CC=\`which gcc\` pyenv install 3.8.6` finds `gcc` bin automatically and set `CC`to  the path of found bin! if your version is different `gcc` bin, you must set `CC` manually to the path of your desired `gcc` bin! something like `CC=\`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin\` pyenv install 3.8.6` without asking `which` to find it!

Answer (score 3):

Me help as:

```
brew install gcc@11
```

after:

```
CC=`which gcc-11` pyenv install 3.8.12
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I realized my pyenv version was out of date. I updated it using homebrew by running:

```
brew install pyenv
```

and then running

```
pyenv install 3.10.6
```

worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this linked really helped: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/703557

It seems you can download 3.8.13 fine if you installed it via homebrew.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I faced the same issue and the solution that worked for me was to install the version manually, here are the steps I performed to get it done:

1. Download the python-3.8.10 version here: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3810/
2. Once downloaded, double-click to install through the installation wizard.
3. Once completed, from finder or terminal open the directory where it got installed: `/Applications/Python 3.8`
4. Run the `Install Certificates.command`, wait until it completes.
5. In the same path, run `Update Shell Profile.command`
6. You are all set, to validate it run from the terminal: `python3 --version`

To setup a virtual environment for python version 3.8.10 installed manually:

1. `pip install --upgrade pip`
2. `pip install virtualenv`
3. `cd my_project_folder/`
4. `virtualenv venv`
5. `source venv/bin/activate`
6. To deactivate once finish working, run: `deactivate`

You can get more information about setting up the virtual environment here: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#