# Lost python executable file after upgrading to macos Monterary

Tags: python-3.x, macos, anaconda, conda

After updating to macos monterary, I lost the python binary file in an anaconda environment. All the library and binaries are there except the python executable file. I am wondering if someone faced this problem? How can I recover this environment?

Comment: You can use `python3` or (better) install your own python as discussed e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71577626/issues-installing-python-3-8-10-on-macos-12-3-monterey

Comment: Could you please list the `pyth*` files in environment's `bin/` directory? Like `ls -lh path/to/bin/pyth*`. (add result to question body)

Comment: @merv I found the problem and the solution. My answer below explains the problem and what the solution was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that my anaconda environment has a link to a python binary in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3`. For some reason, python binary was deleted from there when I upgraded my macOS. My solution was simply to install xcode one more time via the command: `xcode-select --install`