# Python turtle graphics are not working on MacOS Mojave 12.3

Tags: python, macos, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm writing a python program using turtle graphics on  When the turtle window opens up it is glitching and blinking but now showing any graphics.

```py
import turtle

turtle.up()
turtle.write("hello world")
turtle.done()
```

[image: glitching turtle screen]

There's a similar unresolved question on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/CodingHelp/comments/s81vk4/does_anyone_know_how_to_fix_this_turtle_graphics/).

I'm not sure what is wrong and how to fix it.

```
MacOS Mojave 12.3
Python 3.10.6
PythonTurtle == 0.3.2
```

Edit: This snippet works on ubuntu

Comment: [Please post some code.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Added reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

Brutal fix. ‍

Some combination of MacOS version, Python version and tkinter configuration create this issue.

I followed the steps in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60469203/7588896).

However there is a small change, with MacOS Mojave 12.3, Python 3.8.13 must be installed. [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71779344)

So the updated steps are below.

```bash
brew install tcl-tk
env \
  PATH="$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/bin:$PATH" \
  LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib" \
  CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/include" \
  PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib/pkgconfig" \
  CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/include" \
  PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-tcltk-includes='-I$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6'" \
  pyenv install 3.8.13
```